# Thread not staying Alive - IllegalStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is a snippet from a little program I am making using threads.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Before: " + thread.isAlive());
if (!thread.isAlive()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thread is not alive.");
    thread.start();
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "After: " + thread.isAlive());
```

This code is activated using a button. When I press the button the first time, I correctly get "Before: false" and then "After: true".
When I press the button again, I incorrectly get "Before: false" and then "After: true", but expect Before: true, since I am not destroying the thread or overriding the variable.

I believe that this is what is causing IllegalStateException which I am getting (correct me if I am wrong on that too!)

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
public class SomeClass extends Applet
{

private ClassThatExtendsThread thread;

public void init()
{
    super.init();

    //Some UI elements are created here.

    thread = new ClassThatExtendsThread (/*there are some parameters*/);
}
```

Comment: Where and how are you intiializing `thread`?

Comment: *I believe that this is what is causing IllegalStateException which I am getting*: what is *this*? What is the full stack trace of the exception? I would rather say that this is the *consequence* of the exception you're getting, and that is probably causing the thread to die.

Comment: I have added in how the thread class is being stored and instantiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a thread has completed running it is considered dead. Calling `isAlive` on the same thread at this point will always return a result of `false`. The [JavaDoc for Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29) does mention this:

```
public final boolean isAlive()

Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not
yet died.
```

If you are not re-instantiating your thread instance in-between calls to your code snippet then you will definitely get an IllegalStateException. This is because you attempt to start a thread that has already been terminated:

```
if (!thread.isAlive()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thread is not alive.");
    thread.start();
}
```

For future reference, note that you can query a thread state via the `getState` method, which should help with analyzing errors, at the least.

Comment: So does it finish running when it reaches the end of the run() function? How do I allow other buttons inside this class to call other functions in the thread that are not run(). Maybe with a loop inside run? But then it will never exit.

Comment: So how do I prevent it from terminating? I don't really want to re-instantiate because I lose everything inside.

Comment: What you are doing doesn't sound like a use case for threads. What you want is a listener class that you can dispatch too based on events occurring in your main UI.

Comment: @AntonyDAndrea: if threads is really what you want, then you should use a unique Runnable instance, holding the state, and construct and start a new thread from this runnable each time you want to "restart" it.

Comment: @Perception I agree. Unfortunately, my University are insisting that this coursework is done with Threads.

Comment: @JBNizet So instead of the class extending thread, make it implement Runnable?

Comment: Yes, exactly. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html.

Answer (score 0):

You must store the *thread* variable as a class member and create it only once. Most probably, you are storing it as a local variable and creating it everytime you push the button.

Comment: I have added in how the thread class is being stored and instantiated

Comment: Changing a few internal variables, nothing more.